# In wrestling, how is scoring measured?

Tags: rules, scoring, wrestling

In wrestling, whether it be at the collegiate (collegiate wrestling) or high school (scholastic wrestling) level, how is wrestling scored on a per match in addition to a team basis?

Comment: I now just noticed you were asking for scoring in collegiate/high school wrestling...which is widely used in the US. These differ from international styles as presented in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Pages 34-40 of the [International Wrestling Rules](http://www.fila-wrestling.com/images/documents/lutte/wr230107.pdf) published by the International Federation of Associated Wrestling Styles (FILA), the governing body of international amateur wrestling, contains more details on scoring as it relates to greco-roman, freestyle, and women's wrestling.

---

**Takedown:** awarded when the wrestler gains control of his opponent from a neutral position in which three points (eg. two arms and head, two knees one arm (or head), or two arms one knee) are controlled

- 5 points: awarded when a wrestler throws his
  opponent off the mat from either the standing or [par terre](http://www.j-archive.com/media/2007-01-08_DJ_19.jpg) (starting)
  position, and the opponent's feet go
  above his head into the "danger position"  <sub>(see definition below)</sub>
- 3 points: awarded when a wrestler throws his opponent off the mat but does not bring him into a danger position, or takes his opponent from his feet or
  stomach to his back or side into the danger position
- 1 point: awarded when a wrestler takes his opponent from his feet to his stomach
  or side in which his back or shoulders are not exposed to the
  mat but are controlled

**Reversal** (1 point): awarded when a wrestler gains control over his opponent when the opponent has initial control

**Exposure** (2-3 points): awarded when a wrestler exposes or places (but not pins) his opponent's back to the mat for several seconds  <sub>(also see "danger position" below | more details on exposure on p. 35-37)</sub>

**Out-of-Bounds** (1 point): awarded to a wrestler when his opponent places his foot into the [protection area](http://www.sportspectator.com/fancentral/wrestling/Wrestling_Diagram.gif)

**Stalling** (1 point): awarded to a wrestler when his opponent flees a hold or refuses to start

**Penalties**

- 1-2 points:  awarded to a wrestler when his opponent commits an infraction (eg. fleeing, intending to injure, striking, holding illegally, etc.)...the wrestler also is awarded choice of position to the opponent while the opponent is awarded a caution
- 1 point: awarded to a wrestler when his opponent takes an injury timeout (except when the opponent is bleeding) or regularly refuses to take an ordered hold

---

Definition of "**danger position**":  <sub>(p. 35)</sub>

> A wrestler shall be considered in the 'danger position' when the line
>   of his back (or the  line of his shoulders) vertically or in parallel
>   with the mat, forms an angle of less than 90  degrees to the said mat
>   and when he resists with the upper part of his body to avoid a 
>   'fall'.